# SQL Agent After installation not able to start

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, permissions, sql-agent

`SQL Server 2012 SQL Agent` will not start after installation.
Checked permissions, on surface configurations, all OK, have tried to run it as another account
no Joy. The error i am receiving is the following :

The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult the event log for applicable logs for details.

Event log tracked down with these details :

```
Faulting application SQLAGENT.EXE, version 2011.110.3128.0, time stamp 0x50de7939, faulting
module SQLSVC.dll, version 6.0.6002.18881, time stamp 0x51da3d16, exception code 0xc0000142, 
fault offset 0x00000000000b6fc8, process id 0xdb8, application start time 0x01d02a7019de72d7.
```

Bit more information i have gathered on the failure. Please note i have run already the command : `EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'Agent XPs'`with

```
EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options',1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options'
```

===================================

```
Unable to start service SQLSERVERAGENT on server WDBTEST1. (mscorlib)
```

---

Program Location:

Server stack trace:

```
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.Service.Start()
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[]
 args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, 
 IMessageSink replySink)
```

Exception rethrown at [0]:

```
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)
  at   
  Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.
  ObjectExplorer.ServiceActionHandler.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
  at 
  Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.
  ServiceControlProgress.ActionCompletedHandler(IAsyncResult result)
```

===================================

```
Service Request Timeout (ObjectExplorer)
```

---

Program Location:

at

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer
.Service.CheckServiceActionReturnValueS 
uccess(UInt32 returnValue)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.Service.Start()
```

Comment: Please note i also tried a SQL 2012 Repair from The Installation Disk

Comment: found a similar issue, check if it helps: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=190864

Comment: Thanks Vishal, I've followed the steps in the article with talks about finding the Reg Key for the SQLAGENT.OUT file pointing to the correct location. So i did in fact not find in there any SQLAGENT.OUT file in the location, so i have created one, but still no luck. Agent unable to start

Comment: you might want to ask this question on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question has been reposted on dba.stackexchange.com at: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/88741/sql-agent-after-installation-not-able-to-start

Comment: Yes Added to DBA, but with no resolution yet.